# What is the best way to read thousands of files into Matlab for processing in time series applications?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to import thousands of tif files into Matlab for time-series analysis.

```
tifFiles = dir('*.tif');

for k = 1:length(tifFiles)
    A{k} = imread(tifFiles(k).name);
end
```

And I store the files as a cell within a cell.

But how can I access the files related to a particular time period. For example, I want to grab all files between x and y time that is a subset of all the files in the directory.

In R, I could do it using lists, but I am not sure how to do it in Matlab. Also, I lost the file names when I import the data into A, so I am not able to keep track of the time.

What is the best way to do this kind of work in Matlab?

```
Data: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gcgfx4w9lg28uci/AABmr2tAUO8FouF0wfpbDoLqa?dl=0
```

Edit: I determine the time of a particular image from the filename.  For example, PRECIPRATE.20110612.000500 is 00:05 AM on 12th of June, 2011

Comment: Also: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Adriaan Just a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @Adriaan I am happy with a solution to this specific problem as well. How can I store the data in an easily accessible way? Thanks.

Comment: I have removed the part requesting to external resources.

Comment: How do you determine the time for a particular image? By its index? By the file name? By the file date?

Comment: I determine it by the filename. For example, PRECIPRATE.20110612.000500 is 00:05 AM on 12th of June, 2011.

Comment: Here's one possible approach... looking for others. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616107/looping-file-names-with-txt-and-date-in-matlab

Comment: Aside from your question, to speed up the reading of all your files you might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157606/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-load-multiple-image-tiff-file-in-matlab) question and answer from gnovice and Jonas,

Comment: Thank you. That was a good one. I will pre-allocate A to speed up the ingestion. However, I am still confused how to use the regex solution provided above...

Comment: If you have a recent version of MATLAB, I'd suggest looking at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagedatastore-object.html too.

Comment: @akamath Thank you. That looks interesting. Is there any particular advantage to doing it this way? I have latest version of Matlab

Comment: Oh. Turns out I have 2014a. Datastore doesn't work. Any alternatives?